# Fastai pip generates error while installing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, installation

When i install Fastai 1.0.6 it generates this painful error. Same kinda error, a bit different from this done also comes when i try to install Bottleneck 1.3.2 using pip. I have already installed VS build tools 2019, Cuda 10.2 and Stable 1.5 version of PyTorch GPU installed. Also I have already installed PyTorch and Fastai in my conda. It's generating the same error when I tried uninstalling Fastai from conda.

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\sk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' 'c:\users\sk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\SK\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vwpeg743\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'2.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'2.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"''
       cwd: None
  Complete output (44 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\users\sk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "c:\users\sk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "c:\users\sk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 26, in <module>
      sys.exit(_main())
    File "c:\users\sk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 73, in main
      command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
    File "c:\users\sk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py", line 104, in create_command
      module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
    File "c:\users\sk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "c:\users\sk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 24, in <module>
      from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand, with_cleanup
    File "c:\users\sk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 16, in <module>
      from pip._internal.index.package_finder import PackageFinder
    File "c:\users\sk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 21, in <module>
      from pip._internal.index.collector import parse_links
    File "c:\users\sk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 14, in <module>
      from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests
    File "c:\users\sk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
      from . import utils
    File "c:\users\sk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 25, in <module>
      from . import certs
    File "c:\users\sk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\certs.py", line 15, in <module>
      from pip._vendor.certifi import where
    File "c:\users\sk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\certifi\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
      from .core import contents, where
    File "c:\users\sk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\certifi\core.py", line 12, in <module>
      from importlib.resources import read_text
    File "c:\users\sk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\importlib\resources.py", line 11, in <module>
      from typing import Iterable, Iterator, Optional, Set, Union   # noqa: F401
    File "c:\users\sk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\typing.py", line 1357, in <module>
      class Callable(extra=collections_abc.Callable, metaclass=CallableMeta):
    File "c:\users\sk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\typing.py", line 1005, in __new__
      self._abc_registry = extra._abc_registry
  AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution
Uninstall typing using 'pip uninstall typing' and it fixes everything including the installation of bottleneck and fastai too